# Java heap space in netbeans.. but I've increased the heap size already!

Tags: java, netbeans, out-of-memory

I'm having an issue with netbeans and Java. My program needs to be able to cope with large files being uploaded via an arraylist. So I used -Xmx512m to increase the maximum heap size via the netbeans.conf file.

I know that netbeans is catching the change, and I've restarted multiple times to make sure it is. Still, my program continues to crash with a Java heap space memory error when the total memory parameter is only 66650112 bytes; that is, 64M-ish.

How can I force this particular class, procedure, whatever, to allow more memory allocation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you just configured the maximum heap size of netbeans IDE itself and not your program.

Go to your project "**properties**", select "**Run**" category. In the "**VM Options**" text box put your arguments (`-Xmx512m`).

Comment: This only appears to set jvm when running the program as opposed to debugging a specific class.  Is there a way to set the jvm options when in debug mode?

Comment: I ran into an out of heap space exception as well, but I'm using Eclipse. This post helped me figure it out, but here's a more detailed set of instructions for Eclipse: I went to "**Properties**" => "**Run/DebugSettings**". Then I edited the launch configuration for the application, clicked over to the "**Arguments**" tab, and added `-Xmx512m` in the "**VM arguments**" text box.

Answer (score 2):

try on **Tools** -> **Servers** -> on the **Platform** tab 
there is a VM option below Java Platform.

Answer (score 1):

I believe editing netbeans.conf only changes the maximum the JVM that runs the IDE can use. You'll need to change the project configuration for your program (Because it probably runs in a different Java VM).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this link](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#deploy)  for the NetBeans help on setting project properties and in particular the properties for running a project.

VM Options is where you need to add the -Xmx512m

Answer (score 0):

VM Options is where you need to add the -Xmx512m.....

as well as -Xms512m

since:

-Xms512m -> initial Java heap size
-Xmx512m -> max Java heap size

thus you would add, in your case: 
 -Xmx512m -Xms512

in the VM options textfield....

Comment: What is difference between setting heap size in VM options in netbeans and setting JVM-parameter heap size on Glassfish admin console?

Answer (score 0):

Goto project Properties window. set addition compiler option in Build>Compiling tab to
 -Xmx512m