# Netbeans getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, java-me, memory-leaks

I'm executing my j2me project and I'm getting this error:

```
TRACE: <at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError>, Exception caught in Display class
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
   (stack trace incomplete)
```

My .jar size is 612KB and I had search and found this: [Java heap space in netbeans.. but I've increased the heap size already!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705605/java-heap-space-in-netbeans-but-ive-increased-the-heap-size-already)

But as shown in this case, I am not able to find VMoption in properties-Run.

Where can I get the screenshow or the exact file where I have to increase the heap size of Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [obfuscator to obfuscate your code](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/midletsize/) . and 612 kb is considered as a large file for java-me.

You can increase memory and made it working but it will fail in real time env. so I would suggest you to work in dev with real time conf.

> right click your project > properties > obfuscating > obfuscation level > high >build your app

Comment: Hello,i am not getting the "OBFUSCATOR" can u please explain it in detail

Comment: i had done that now the size of jar file decrease to 501KB from 612KB.But i an still facing the problem at same place.