# Java Heap Space Exception

Tags: java, netbeans

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at masterCustomer.initComponents(masterCustomer.java:32)
at masterCustomer.<init>(masterCustomer.java:11)
at MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:19)
at loginForm.<init>(loginForm.java:17)
at MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:20)
at loginForm.<init>(loginForm.java:17)
at MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:20)
at loginForm.<init>(loginForm.java:17)
at MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:20)
at loginForm.<init>(loginForm.java:17)
```

anyone know how to fix this problem? this problem happening after i generate setter and getter from netbeans...

Comment: It looks like you have an infinite loop somewhere in your code... please post the code.

Comment: Try increasing your heap space http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705605/java-heap-space-in-netbeans-but-ive-increased-the-heap-size-already

Comment: You should put capitalized initials to your class names, at least for consistency.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `loginForm` needs a reference to the `MainFrame`, and the other way around. You get an infinite loop at these 2 lines:

```
 loginForm.java:17
 MainFrame.java:20
```

Comment: More exactly, MainFrame makes a `new loginForm()` which makes a `new MainFrame()` but the analysis / end result is the same.

Comment: You can't say this for certain without seeing the code, but it is a good guess and a common beginner mistake.

Comment: got it, the problem is on MainFrame main = new MainFrame(); i should be MainFrame main ;  case closed, thanks for all the help