# Netbeans 7.4 increasing Heap Size

Tags: java, memory, netbeans-7, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

I have a problem with my **Java application** that require some extra space into the **heap**. I know that ion Netbeans user can increase heap size by

> project->properties->run->JVM Option.. or using Netbeans.conf file.

I have tried adding:

```
 Netbeans.conf:
 -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx512m -J-XX:PermSize=512m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

And/or into project properties

```
-Xms512m -Xmx512m
```

but my problem still remain. And application crash whit **`OufOfMemory error`** when it reach about 60m of memory...

Have you got any alternative solutions?

If it can help.. I'm using windows as SO and `Netbeans 7.4` and `JDK 7.u45`

Comment: Without more details on your system and code we cannot really help. If you get an out of memory error and you know its not a heap size issue? then does your System/OS have enough "free" memory to spare?

Comment: Maybe you're just using a lot of memory. What does the program do? Also when the program loads print the value of `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` to verify your Xms is being respected.

Comment: the default max heap size is 1GB or 1/4 the memory of your system :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined You've probably decreased the heap with those flags

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705605/java-heap-space-in-netbeans-but-ive-increased-the-heap-size-already?rq=1 You shouldn't touch the Netbeans.conf file add the flags to your project properties

Comment: The initial output of getFreeMemory() statement il about 64M ... Seems that net beans ignore configuration into VM Options or into Netbeans.conf. (My machine has 4Gb of Ram)

Comment: Simply remove all the arguments.. make it blank and then try. Sometimes without any arguments it works...