# NetBeans 8: Java heap space error on start of the IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

Every time I start my NetBeans 8.0.1 I get an unexpected exception: Java heap space.

I don't run any programs in NetBeans, it's happening while it does "Background scanning of projects" (I have some node and angular projects open).

I increased the JVM heap size in the netbeans config as stated here:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSettingHeapSize

... changed the GC as stated here:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqGCPauses

... and added some other options that were suggested on this site, e.g. here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15461021/1686888

These are my options in the config file:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms256m -J-Xmx512m -J-XX:PermSize=256m  -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -J-Xverify:none"
```

Increasing Xmx and Permsize to 2048/1024 or deleting them to let Netbeans set it automatically doesn't help either.

Also, setting the VM-Options of the project itself as statet here:
[Java heap space in netbeans.. but I've increased the heap size already!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705605/java-heap-space-in-netbeans-but-ive-increased-the-heap-size-already)
... does not help, because that option does not exist in my projects.

What else can I try?